How to inject entries in flink-conf.yaml at runtime to safely pass secrets?
I’m running a Flink application in Kubernetes using the Flink Kubernetes Operator, and I need to securely pass the Datadog API key for the Datadog reporter. The challenge is that this key needs to be included in the flink-conf.yaml file, which is stored in a ConfigMap and storing secrets in a ConfigMap is not secure.
I have also created a JIRA ticket suggesting the use of environment variables to pass this API key, but this feature may not be backported to earlier versions of Flink.
So at this point what I'm thinking is to somehow inject API key into flink-conf.yaml at runtime.
Is this doable? Are there other alternatives?
Update: I have tried passing it as FLINK_PROPERTIES env but that didn't work, metrics aren't reported.
containers:
  - name: flink-main-container
    env:
      - name: FLINK_PROPERTIES
        value: "metrics.reporter.dghttp.apikey: key"

